# Как вывести переменные в произвольном порядке?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести произвольно три переменные.

```js
let string1;
let string2;
let string3;

string1 = prompt ("Введите первое слово: ");
string2 = prompt ("Введите второе слово: ");
string3 = prompt ("Введите третье слово: ");


console.log(string3 + string2 + string1 && string1 + string2 + string3 && string2 + string1 + string3);
```

Comment: Что значит  *Нужно вывести произвольно три переменные.*?

Comment: в рандомном порядке каждый раз выводить string1,string2,string3

Comment: а в чем смысл этого? Какую задачу пытаетесь решить? Расскажите про задачу, может есть более удобный\простой способ ее решить.

Comment: Получить от пользователя 3 строки и вывести их в произвольном порядке одной командой (конкатенация)

Answer (score 0):

Получить от пользователя 3 строки и вывести их в произвольном порядке одной командой

```js
let strings = [];

strings.push(prompt("Введите первое слово: "));
strings.push(prompt("Введите второе слово: "));
strings.push(prompt("Введите третье слово: "));

console.log(strings.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1).join(" "));
```